# Unable to connect to a TCPClient on another computer

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcplistener

So I have two laptops connected to the same wifi network with one running a very simple server and the other a very simple client connecting to it.  When I run both the server and the client on one laptop they connect without a problem, but when running one on each laptop the client cannot connect to the server.

The code for the server is this:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Utils
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A base server which handles listening for client connections and has simple API to communicate back and forth
    /// </summary>
    public class BaseServer
    {
        #region Properties and Fields

        /// <summary>
        /// The listener we can use to detect incoming connections from clients to the server
        /// </summary>
        private TcpListener Listener { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Our interface to the single client we are supporting for now
        /// </summary>
        public Comms ClientComms { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether we have clients connected
        /// </summary>
        public bool Connections { get; private set; }

        #endregion

        public BaseServer()
        {
            Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1490);
            Listener.Start();

            ListenForNewClient();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts an asynchronous check for new connections
        /// </summary>
        private void ListenForNewClient()
        {
            Listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(AcceptClient, null);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Callback for when a new client connects to the server
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="asyncResult"></param>
        protected virtual void AcceptClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            ClientComms = new Comms(Listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(asyncResult));
            ClientComms.OnDataReceived += ProcessMessage;

            ListenForNewClient();
        }

        #region Message Callbacks

        /// <summary>
        /// A function which is called when the Client sends a message to the server.
        /// Override to perform custom message handling
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data"></param>
        protected virtual void ProcessMessage(byte[] data) { }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

And the code for the client is this:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Utils
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A base client class which connects and communicates with a remote server
    /// </summary>
    public class BaseClient
    {
        #region Properties and Fields

        /// <summary>
        /// The interface to the server
        /// </summary>
        public Comms ServerComms { get; private set; }

        #endregion

        public BaseClient(string ipAddress, int portNumber = 1490)
        {
            // Attempt to connect
            try
            {
                ServerComms = new Comms(new TcpClient(ipAddress, portNumber));
                ServerComms.OnDataReceived += OnMessageReceived;
                ServerComms.OnDisconnect += OnServerDisconnect;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connection failed");
            }
        }

        #region Callbacks

        /// <summary>
        /// A function which is called when this client receives a message.
        /// Override to perform behaviour when custom messages arrive.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data"></param>
        protected virtual void OnMessageReceived(byte[] data) { }

        /// <summary>
        /// A function called when this client can no longer communicate to the server it is connected to
        /// </summary>
        protected virtual void OnServerDisconnect() { }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

The server is started from the main loop like this:

```
using System;

namespace BuildServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BaseServer server = new BaseServer();
            while (true)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the Client is started like this:

```
using System;
using Utils;

namespace BuildServerClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BaseClient client = new BaseClient();

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ready");
                string message = Console.ReadLine();
                client.ServerComms.Send(message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One final class is a Comms class which is really a wrapper around the TCPClient and not really used currently, but I am adding it for the same of completeness.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using static Utils.Delegates;

namespace Utils
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An interface to a client.
    /// Hides the nuts and bolts and provides a public interface of just data input and output from a data sender/receiver.
    /// </summary>
    public class Comms
    {
        #region Properties and Fields

        private TcpClient Client { get; set; }
        private MemoryStream ReadStream { get; set; }
        private MemoryStream WriteStream { get; set; }
        private BinaryReader Reader { get; set; }
        private BinaryWriter Writer { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Useful buffer for reading packeted messages from the server
        /// </summary>
        private byte[] ReadBuffer { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// An event that is fired when this Comms receives a message
        /// </summary>
        public event OnDataReceived OnDataReceived;

        /// <summary>
        /// An event that is fired when this Comms can no longer communicate with the client sending it messages
        /// </summary>
        public event OnDisconnect OnDisconnect;

        #endregion

        public Comms(TcpClient client)
        {
            Client = client;
            ReadStream = new MemoryStream();
            WriteStream = new MemoryStream();
            Reader = new BinaryReader(ReadStream);
            Writer = new BinaryWriter(WriteStream);

            ReadBuffer = new byte[2048];
            Client.NoDelay = true;

            StartListening();
        }

        #region Data Sending Functions

        /// <summary>
        /// Convert a string to a byte array and then send to our client
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="client"></param>
        /// <param name="str"></param>
        public void Send(string str)
        {
            SendByteArray(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Send a byte array to our client
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="client"></param>
        /// <param name="bytes"></param>
        protected void SendByteArray(byte[] bytes)
        {
            Writer.Write(bytes);

            int bytesWritten = (int)WriteStream.Position;
            byte[] result = new byte[bytesWritten];

            WriteStream.Position = 0;
            WriteStream.Read(result, 0, bytesWritten);
            WriteStream.Position = 0;

            Client.GetStream().BeginWrite(result, 0, result.Length, null, null);
            Writer.Flush();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Data Receiving Functions

        /// <summary>
        /// Start listening for messages from the server
        /// </summary>
        private void StartListening()
        {
            try
            {
                Client.GetStream().BeginRead(ReadBuffer, 0, 2048, StreamReceived, null);
            }
            catch
            {
                OnDisconnect?.Invoke();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Callback which processes a message sent from the server
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ar"></param>
        private void StreamReceived(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            int bytesRead = 0;
            try
            {
                lock (Client.GetStream())
                {
                    bytesRead = Client.GetStream().EndRead(ar);
                }
            }
            catch { }

            //Create the byte array with the number of bytes read
            byte[] data = new byte[bytesRead];

            //Populate the array
            for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
            {
                data[i] = ReadBuffer[i];
            }

            OnDataReceived?.Invoke(data);

            //Listen for new data
            StartListening();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

The IP Addresses and Port numbers are correct and since it works when running on the same machine, I was thinking it might be a firewall issue or something?  Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be causing this problem?

Comment: What goes wrong exactly?

Comment: It does not connect & times out.  There is a try catch around the section where I create the TCPClient & and it always catches an exception because of timeout.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the firewall (Windows Firewall, or whatever's there) is turned off on the server machine, or there's a firewall exception for your port number.

Comment: I turned off the firewall for private networks, but it still didn't work.  Should I also do it for guest & public networks?

Comment: No the IP address and port number are correct, because it all works when I run both on the same computer (and I am not using local host as my IP address).

Comment: If you're using 127.0.0.1, that's the wrong address.

Comment: I'm not using 127.0.0.1.  I'm using the actual IP Address of my computer and the correct port number.

Comment: Start the server instance.  On the other laptop, try to connect to the server instance using a Telnet client and the correct port number.  You may need to install it (it's part of Windows - see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275(v=ws.10).aspx).  Once it's installed, THIS article (https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH107919.html) proximately describes what I'm getting at.  If telnet can connect, but your client can't, then the problem is with your client.  If telnet can't connect, then there's an issue either with your tcp server, firewall, or the network.

Answer (score 0):

David's answer was correct.  I previously tried it with just the firewall disabled for private networks.  However, I disabled the firewall for guest and public networks and it worked a treat.

The method of testing proposed by codenoir was also very effective at ruling out my client.  I suspected it was something to do with the firewall, but once you rule out the impossible...

Thanks to both